# Android - can't access a downloaded file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write an app that downloads a file with the Android DownloadManager and when done with the download, I want to edit the file. I'm facing a problem when trying to access the file with the following code:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
file.exists() - returns false even though I can view the file with the File Manager app
```

Note: The above lines are written in a BroadcastReciever in the `OnRecieve()` method and the device I'm using does not have external storage.

I tried checking where the code looks for the file by using the `createNewFile()` method yet while that makes the `exists()` method return `true` I can't for the life of me find the created file in the File Manager app.

I have also tried the following URIs:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.max.lucas/files/filename
/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.max.lucas/files/filename
/0/Android/data/com.example.max.lucas/files/filename
/Android/data/com.example.max.lucas/files/filename
/data/com.example.max.lucas/files/filename
/com.example.max.lucas/files/filename
/files/filename
/filename
```

yet none seemed to work.

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.max.lucas" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activities>.....</activities>

    <receiver                 <- Where I'm trying to find and edit the file
        android:name=".rcv_DownloadedFilesHandler"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.max.lucas"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: try to write the path where you already see the file using FileManager App

Comment: have you tried `/storage/emulated/0/Download/filename`?

Comment: the file is downloaded to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.max.lucas/files/filename. The Download folder contains nothing of use

Comment: "I'm facing a problem when trying to access the file with the following code" -- that code is not where you downloaded the file, as `DownloadManager` has no ability to work with your app's `getFilesDir()`. You might consider posting your code that does the downloading. "and the device I'm using does not have external storage" -- [yes, it does](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm trying to access a file that is on the device. About the storage, I meant the device has no sd card installed. Everything is on the internal storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything is on the internal storage

Not from the standpoint of the Android SDK. [Internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) is not [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and neither are [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), in terms of the Android SDK.

> the file is downloaded to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.max.lucas/files/filename

That equates to `new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "filename")`, assuming that your app is running in the device's primary user account (which is typically the case).

`getFilesDir()` points to a location where you can store arbitrary files in your app's corner of internal storage. Your file is on external storage, in an app-specific location.